# What is the equivalent to xargs -r under OsX

Tags: macos, bash, shell

Are they any equivalent under OSX  to the `xargs -r` under Linux ? I'm trying to find a way to interupt a pipe if there's no data.

For instance imagine you do the following:

```
touch test
cat test | xargs -r echo "content: "
```

That doesn't yield any result because xargs interrupts the pipe.

Is there either some *hidden* xargs option or something else to achieve the same result under OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `test` or `[`:

```
if [ -s test ] ; then cat test | xargs echo content: ; fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! In my case as _cat test_ is actually much more complicated in the command line i was trying to execute, with a whole series of commands. But the idea to split in several steps is the right way to do it.  I guess i was too caught in the _single line syndrom_ ;)

Answer (score 3):

The POSIX standard for [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) mandates that the command be executed once, even if there are no arguments.  This is a nuisance, which is why GNU `xargs` has the `-r` option.  Unfortunately, neither BSD (MacOS X) nor the other mainstream Unix versions (AIX, HP-UX, Solaris) support it.

If it is crucial to you, obtain and install GNU `xargs` somewhere that your environment will find it, without affecting the system (so don't replace `/usr/bin/xargs` unless you're a braver man than I am — but `/usr/local/bin/xargs` might be OK, or `$HOME/bin/xargs`, or …).

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way to determine if the xargs you are running is GNU or not.  I set `$gnuargs` to either "true" or "false" and then have a function that replaces xargs and does the right thing.

On Linux, FreeBSD and MacOS this script works for me.  The POSIX standard for xargs mandates that the command be executed once, even if there are no arguments.  FreeBSD and MacOS X violate this rule, thus don't need "-r".  GNU finds it annoying, and adds `-r`.  This script does the right thing and can be enhanced if you find a version of Unix that does it some other way.

```
#!/bin/bash

gnuxargs=$(xargs --version 2>&1 |grep -s GNU >/dev/null && echo true || echo false)

function portable_xargs_r() {
  if $gnuxargs ; then
    cat - | xargs -r "$@"
  else
    cat - | xargs "$@"
  fi
}

echo 'this' > foo
echo '=== Expect one line'
portable_xargs_r <foo echo "content: "
echo '=== DONE.'

cat </dev/null > foo
echo '=== Expect zero lines'
portable_xargs_r <foo echo "content: "
echo '=== DONE.'
```

Comment: I hadn't noticed that BSD/macOS `xargs` does things sanely even without the support of the `-r` option, but `xargs ls < /dev/null` doesn't produce anything on my Mac; it behaves as if `-r` were specified.

Comment: Why the `cat`s?

Comment: Why the triple-quotes? AFAICT, the only difference between `"$@"` and `"""$@"""` would be that with the latter, if `portable_xargs_r` is passed no argument, `xargs` would end-up being passed one empty argument, so would prevent it running the  default `echo` command.

Comment: Why the `cat`s: The `cat foo` have been removed. They were there just to keep things parallel.  The `cat -` means "cat standard input" in a portable way, other shells might have shorthands that work too.

Comment: Why the triple quotes: Good catch. They aren't needed and have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty `xargs-r` using a temporary file.

```
#!/bin/sh
t=$(mktemp -t xargsrXXXXXXXXX) || exit
trap 'rm -f $t' EXIT HUP INT TERM
cat >"$t"
test -s "$t" || exit
exec xargs "$@" <"$t"
```

Answer (score 1):

with POSIX `xargs`¹, to avoid running `the-command` when the input is empty, you could use `moreutils`'s `ifne` (for *if not empty*):

```
... | ifne xargs ... the-command ...
```

Or use a `sh` wrapper that checks the number of arguments:

```
... | xargs ... sh -c '[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || exec the-command ... "$@"' sh
```

---

<sup>¹  though one can hardly use `xargs` POSIXly as it doesn't support `-0`, has unspecified behaviour when the input is non-text (like for filenames which on most systems are not guaranteed to be text except in the POSIX locale), parses its input in a very arcane way and that is locale-dependant, and doesn't give any guarantee if any word is more than 255 bytes long!</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure that the input always has at least one line. This may not always be possible, but you'd be surprised how many creative ways this can be done.

Comment: The point of `-r` is to _prevent_ running the command if there are no input lines.

Comment: As such, `echo` is a poor example of a command to run under `xargs -r` because it's pretty harmless. A more common use case is to avoid errors when piping to `xargs kill` or something like that, or of course properly expensive operations and ones which compromise your data integrity would be better examples still.

Answer (score 0):

A typical use case looks like:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -r -0 grep PATTERN
```

Some versions of xargs do not have an `-r` flag. In that case, you can supply /dev/null as the first filename so that grep is never handed an empty list of filenames. Since the pattern will never be found in /dev/null, this won't affect the output:

```
find . -print0 | xargs  -0 grep PATTERN /dev/null
```

Comment: `grep` is not a good example here. If `grep` is not passed any argument, then it will look into its stdin which depending on the `xargs` implementation will be either opened on `/dev/null` or the (empty) pipe from `find`, so omitting `-r` would be harmless here (as long as `grep` is not passed non-standard `-L`/`-r`/`-R`... options).

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the stream has any content:

```
cat test | { if IFS= read -r tmp; then { printf "%s\n" "$tmp"; cat; } | xargs echo "content: "; fi; }
#                                                                                               ^^^ - otherwise just do nothing
#                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - to xargs
#                                                              ^^^ - and the rest of input
#                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - redirect first line
#            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - try reading anything

# or with a function
# even TODO: add the check of `portable_xargs_r` in the other answer and call `xargs -r` when available.
xargs_r() {
   if IFS= read -r tmp; then
       { printf "%s\n" "$tmp"; cat; } | xargs "$@"
   fi
}
cat test | xargs_r echo "content: "
```

This method runs the check inside the pipe inside the subshell, so it effectively can be used in a complicated pipe setup.