# List all local branches without a remote

Tags: git, git-remote

Problem: I want a way of deleting all the local branches I have that do not have a remote. It's easy enough to pipe the names of the branches into a `git branch -D {branch_name}`, but how do I get that list in the first place?

For example:

I create a new branch without a remote:

```
$ git co -b no_upstream
```

I list all my branches, and there's only one with a remote

```
$ git branch -a
master
* no_upstream
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
```

What command can I run to get `no_upstream` as an answer?

I can run `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}` and that will show that it has no remote:

```
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}
error: No upstream configured for branch 'no_upstream'
error: No upstream configured for branch 'no_upstream'
fatal: ambiguous argument '@{u}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

But as this is an error, it won't let me use it or pipe it to other commands. I'm intending to use this as either a shell script alias'd to `git-delete-unbranched` or maybe make a super simple Gem like `git-branch-delete-orphans`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950725/how-do-i-get-git-to-show-me-which-branches-are-tracking-what

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove local branches no longer on remote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-local-branches-no-longer-on-remote)

Answer (score 182):

I recommend using `git branch --format` to specify the exact output you want from the `git branch` command. By doing that, you can pull out just the refname and the upstream, like this:

```
git branch --format "%(refname:short) %(upstream)"
```

It outputs the branches along with the remote branches if they exist, in the following format:

```
25-timeout-error-with-many-targets
31-target-suggestions refs/remotes/origin/31-target-suggestions
54-feedback-link refs/remotes/origin/54-feedback-link
65-digest-double-publish
```

Once you have this nicely formatted output, it's as easy as piping it through `awk` to get your list:

```
git branch --format "%(refname:short) %(upstream)" | awk '{if (!$2) print $1;}'
```

Results in the following output:

```
25-timeout-error-with-many-targets
65-digest-double-publish
```

The `awk` portion prints the first column if there is no second column.

**Bonus: Create an alias**

Make it easy to run by creating an alias in your global `.gitconfig` file (or wherever):

```
[alias]
  local-branches = "!git branch --format '%(refname:short) %(upstream:short)' | awk '{if (!$2) print $1;}'"
```

**Bonus: Remote Filtering**

If for some reason you have multiple tracking remotes for different branches, it's easy enough to specify which remote you want to check against. Just add the remote name to the awk pattern. In my case, it's `origin` so I can do this:

```
git branch --format "%(refname:short) %(upstream)" | awk '$2 !~/\/origin\// { print $1 }'
```

Important: The backslash needs to be escaped in the alias or else you will have an invalid gitconfig file.

---

### Previous Answer

The previous answer was functionally similar, but used the following as it's starting point. Over time, commenters have pointed out that a regex is unreliable due to the variance possible in a commit message, so I no longer recommend this method. But, here it is for reference:

I recently discovered `git branch -vv` which is the "very verbose" version of the `git branch` command.

It outputs the branches along with the remote branches if they exist, in the following format:

```
  25-timeout-error-with-many-targets    206a5fa WIP: batch insert
  31-target-suggestions                 f5bdce6 [origin/31-target-suggestions] Create target suggestion for team and list on save
* 54-feedback-link                      b98e97c [origin/54-feedback-link] WIP: Feedback link in mail
  65-digest-double-publish              2de4150 WIP: publishing-state
```

Once you have this nicely formatted output, it's as easy as piping it through `cut` and `awk` to get your list:

```
git branch -vv | cut -c 3- | awk '$3 !~/\[/ { print $1 }'
```

Comment: whats that `WIP:` anyway..? isn't that what a stash command creates..?

Comment: @igrek That's just a prefix I used in the commit message. Nothing specific to git.

Comment: when i do `git branch -vv`, even if a remote branch exists and matches my local branch, i would not see the `[origin/branch-name]` alongside the result. I had to `diff` two lists of branches to actually figure out what was local only.

Comment: `git branch -vv | grep -v origin/` is enough for me

Comment: Doesn't this miss the remote branches marked `gone`?

Comment: Any matching like that won't work if the commit message contains anything like that.  For example, all our commit messages are "[ABC-nnnn] description", therefore every single one would match your regex.  If matching "[origin" won't always produce the right results.

Comment: The updated answer does not work sorry. It returns the following for two branches with no upstream.... https://gist.github.com/rtfmoz2/587c0859a61936aa18133a34b62ea9fd

Answer (score 51):

[`git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) (without any options) lists only local branches, but you don't know if they are tracking a remote branch or not.

Usually those local branches should be deleted once merged into `main` (as seen in [this issue of git-sweep](https://github.com/arc90/git-sweep/issues/5)):

```
git branch --no-contains main --merged main| xargs git branch -d
```

Since 2020/2021, [most repositories use `main` as a default branch instead of `master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65799427/6309).

This isn't as complete as you want, but it is a start.

> With `--merged`, only branches merged into the named commit (i.e. the branches whose tip commits are reachable from the named commit) will be listed.

Comment: To also include remote branches without a local branch, use `git branch -a --merged`.

Comment: NOTE: a lot of repos have now switched from `master` to `main` as their primary branch so if that's the case, make sure to update it.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Good point, thank you. 10 years later, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 35):

I have a similar issue. I want to remove all local branches that were tracking remote branches that are now deleted.  I am finding that `git remote prune origin` was insufficient to remove the branches that I want gone. Once the remote is deleted, I want the local to go away too. Here is what worked for me:

From my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  prune-branches = !git remote prune origin && git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -r git branch -d
```

Here is a `git config --global ...` command for easily adding this as `git prune-branches`:

```
git config --global alias.prune-branches '!git remote prune origin && git branch -vv | grep '"'"': gone]'"'"' | awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"' | xargs -r git branch -d'
```

*NOTE*: I changed the `-d` to `-D` in my actual configuration, because I don't want to hear Git complain about unmerged branches. You *may* want this functionality as well. If so, simply use `-D` instead of `-d` at the end of that command.

Also, FWIW, your global configuration file would almost always be `~/.gitconfig`.

**(OS X Fix)**

As written, this does not work on OS X because of the use of `xargs -r` (thanks, [Korny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196463/korny)).

The `-r` is to prevent `xargs` from running `git branch -d` without a branch name, which will result in an error message "`fatal: branch name required`". If you don't mind the error message, you can simply remove the `-r` argument to `xargs` and you're all set.

However, if you don't want to see an error message (and really, who could blame you) then you'll need something else that checks for an empty pipe. If you might be able to use [ifne](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ifne) from [moreutils](https://rentes.github.io/unix/utilities/2015/07/27/moreutils-package/). You would insert `ifne` before `xargs`, which will stop `xargs` from running with empty data. *NOTE*: `ifne` considers **anything** to be not empty, this includes blank lines, so you may still see that error message. I've not tested this on OS X.

Here is that `git config` line with `ifne`:

```
git config --global alias.prune-branches '!git remote prune origin && git branch -vv | grep '"'"': gone]'"'"' | awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"' | ifne xargs git branch -d'
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert this into a "git config --global..." command? From an instruction/how-to-wiki-for-dummies point of view it is easy to pass on instead of saying "Find out your git config files, use editor to edit it then run commands"

Comment: Note that [xargs -r doesn't work on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803987/what-is-the-equivalent-to-xargs-r-under-osx)

Comment: Good to know. I don't know what the "no run if empty" option would be for OSX.

Answer (score 21):

This works for me:

`git branch -vv | grep -v origin`

(if your remote is named anything other than origin, substitute that).

This will list all the branches that aren't tracking a remote, which sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: This will list branches that used to have a remote but do not anymore even if you run `git fetch --prune`.

Comment: IMO, it is better looking for ": gone]" instead of filtering out "origin"

Answer (score 20):

Late edit:

Better is

```
git for-each-ref  --format='%(refname:short) %(upstream)'  refs/heads \
| awk '$2 !~/^refs\/remotes/'
```

---

On GNU/anything

```
for b in `git branch|sed s,..,,`; do
    git config --get branch.$b.remote|sed Q1 && echo git branch -D $b
done
```

If more than a handful of branches were likely, there'd be better ways, using `comm -23` on the output of `git branch|sed|sort` and `git config -l|sed|sort`.

Comment: @nmr s/git.*Q1/test $(git config --get branch.$b.remote|sed q|wc -1) = 1/

Answer (score 16):

I synthetise my own Git command to get the `origin/***: gone` branches:

```
git remote prune origin && git branch -vv | cut -c 3- | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 -r echo git branch -d
```

`git remote prune origin && git branch -vv` will print branches in verbose mode.

`cut -c 3-` will remove very first characters.

`grep ': gone]'` will print only the *gone* remote branches.

`awk '{print $1}'` will print the branch name.

`xargs -n1 -r echo git branch -d` will print the `git branch -d` command to remove branches (-n1 will manage one command per time, -r to avoid issuing command if no branch is present).

*HINT:* remove the "echo" command to *run* the commands instead of print only, I left this in the command to check commands before issuing to git.

*HINT 2:* issue `git branch -D` if and only if you are sure you want to remove unmerged branches

Comment: from this I did my personal [git gone](https://gist.github.com/stefanofiorentino/ed6bd40424016054e2a090a71cd460d4)

Comment: This is _by far_ the cleanest solution I've found, nice! I've never spent the time studying `awk`, I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: This is the only one which got all branches that have been merged, deleted, or otherwise locally for me.

Comment: Why the cut? I get the same output with or without it

Comment: remove the first three lines is better than discard them by the following grep, but result is the same, you right.

Answer (score 5):

The most voted answer here does not work on my system see [gist](https://gist.github.com/rtfmoz2/587c0859a61936aa18133a34b62ea9fd)

This following does work and is reasonably clean.

```sh
git branch -v | awk '$3 == "[gone]" { print $1 }' | xargs git branch -D
```

Use -d if you don't want to delete un-merged branches.

Comment: This works. Small note: If you use 'squash merge', you need to use -D, since branches are technically not merged.

Comment: BIG note - the OQ is about _listing_ branches, while this answer _deletes_ them.

Answer (score 3):

Here is something I have used in PowerShell with comments to explain what it's doing. In an attempt to make it clear what's going on, I've not used any abbreviated PowerShell commands (aliases). Feel free to compress it to your desired level of crypticness :)

```
$verboseList = @(git branch -vv)
foreach ($line in $verboseList)
{
    # Get the branch name
    $branch = [regex]::Match($line, "\s(\S+)\s").Captures.Groups[1].Value
    # Check if the line contains text to indicate if the remote is deleted
    $remoteGone = $line.Contains(": gone]")
    # Check if the line does not contain text to indicate it is a tracking branch (i.e., it's local)
    $isLocal = !($line.Contains("[origin/"))
    if ($remoteGone -or $isLocal)
    {
        # Print the branch name
        $branch
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `%(upstream:track)` [formatting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref):

```
git branch --format "%(refname:short) %(upstream:track)" |
  awk '{if($2=="[gone]") print $1;}'
```

Output of `git branch -v` is unreliable for parsing.

Git version 2.37.1

Comment: Why am I the first to post this answer in 10 years?

Comment: Good point. Upvoted. When I wrote my answer in 2013, I did not have Git 2.5 and the `upstream:track` syntax I rediscovered [with `git for-each-ref`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20499690/6309).

Answer (score 2):

I use

`git branch --no-merged main`

This will list branches without an `origin/` counterpart (obviously) as well as branches that have commits that are have not made it to the target branch yet, so, a good list of branches to look at for housekeeping after I've merged my PR that involved multiple sessions of "backup-rebase-seeifitworks-letmetryanotherway"

```
--no-merged [<commit>]
Only list branches whose tips are not reachable from the specified commit (HEAD if not specified). Implies --list.
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the existing answers seems to work for me.

Here's my solution to list local branches that are not also remote

```
comm -13 <(git branch -r | sed 's/origin\/\(.*\)/\1/g' | cut -c 3-) <(git branch | cut -c 3-)
```

And here's an explanation of how it works:

1. Consider the list of all remote branches (without 'origin/' or leading spaces)
   `git branch -r | sed 's/origin\/\(.*\)/\1/g' | cut -c 3-`
2. Consider the list of all local branches (without asterisks or leading spaces)
   `git branch | cut -c 3-`
3. Compare these two lists and show me anything in list 2 (my local branches) that isn't in list 1 (the list of remote branches)
   `comm -13 <(git branch -r | sed 's/origin\/\(.*\)/\1/g' | cut -c 3-) <(git branch | cut -c 3-)`

> comm can take a combination of the flags -1, -2 and -3 indicating
> which file to suppress lines from (unique to file 1, unique to file 2
> or common to both)

Answer (score 0):

Combining a few of the existing answers:

```
[alias]
        branch-local = !git branch -vv | cut -c 3- | egrep '([0-9a-f]{7} [^[])|(: gone\\])' | sed -E 's/(^.+[0-9a-f]{7} (\\[.+\\])?).*$/\\1/'
```

E.g.:

```
$ git branch-local
autogen_autoreconf      fcfb1c6 [github/autogen_autoreconf: gone]
autotools_documentation 72dc477 [github/autotools_documentation: gone]
cray-mpich-messy        2196f4b
epel-sphinx             cfda770
lammps                  07d96a7 [github/lammps: gone]
lark-error              9ab5d6c [github/lark-error: gone]
no-root2                c3894d1
openmpi-cray            69326cf [github/openmpi-cray: gone]
shellcheck-cleanup      40d90ec
travis-python36         cde072e
update_vagrant_default  4f69f47 [github/update_vagrant_default: gone]
web-docs                e73b4a8
```

Comment: where is this alias defined?

Comment: @ekkis `~/.gitconfig`