# Display local branches that have been "squashed & merged" into master

Tags: git, github, branch

In our team's repository, we work by submitting PRs and we only merge them into master using github's squash & merge functionality. The problem for me is that I can then no longer see branches merged into master with `git branch --merged`, as this will not show branches that have been squashed & merged. My local branches are piling up and it's a pain to review them one by one to see which I can remove. Is there another way to list them?

Comment: if my or any other answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted so that dev can figure that out and don't waste their time on solved problems.

Answer (score 8):

**tl;dr;** Unfortunately, no. You'll have to check the status of your PR on GitHub and, once it has been merged, forcibly delete your local branches with [`git branch -D`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--D).

#### "Squash and merge" Illustrated

The GitHub [Squash and merge](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-pull-request-merges#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits) operation doesn't actually merge your [topic branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddeftopicbranchatopicbranch) ― instead, it squashes all the commits from that branch into a single one, and then *rebases* that commit on top of the target branch.

From the [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-pull-request-merges#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits):

> When you select the **Squash and merge** option on a pull request on GitHub, the pull request's commits are squashed into a single commit.

And the most important part:

> Pull requests with squashed commits are merged using the fast-forward option.

A [fast-forward merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddeffastforwardafast-forward) doesn't create a merge commit ― it simply moves the target branch reference forward so that it points to the same commit as the source branch. This can only be done if the source branch points to a commit that is a *descendant* of the target branch.

So, if your topic branch looks like this in your local repository:

```
         master
         v
o--o--o--o
    \
     A--B--C  <- This is the branch you want to merge with a PR
           ^
           topic
```

When you use [Squash and merge](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-pull-request-merges#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits), GitHub will *rewrite the history* of your `topic` branch so that it looks like this:

```
         master
         v
o--o--o--o
    \
     S  <- This is A, B and C squashed together
     ^
     topic
```

Then, GitHub will *rebase* `topic` on top of `master`. Notice that this will result in a commit that's *different* from the original squashed commit `S` because of the different parent; to distinguish it, we call the rebased commit `S'` (*S prime*):

```
         master
         v
o--o--o--o
          \
           S'
           ^
           topic
```

Finally, the `topic` branch is incorporated into `master` with a [fast-forward merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddeffastforwardafast-forward):

```
            master
            v
o--o--o--o--S'
            ^
            topic
```

This all happens inside the repository that's hosted on GitHub's servers. Meanwhile, on your machine the repository still looks like this:

```
         master
         v
o--o--o--o
    \
     A--B--C
           ^
           topic
```

After you've done [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) on `master`, you'll receive the squashed and rebased commit `S'`:

```
            master
            v
o--o--o--o--S'
    \
     A--B--C
           ^
           topic
```

Git has no way of knowing that commit `S'` contains the combined changes from `A`, `B` and `C`. That's why it will still report `topic` as *unmerged*.

#### A Practical Consideration

Linus Torvalds once [wrote](https://www.mail-archive.com/dri-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg39091.html):

> People can (and probably should) rebase their *private* trees (their own 
>   work). That's a *cleanup*. But never other peoples code. That's a "destroy 
>   history".

He then continues:

> You must never EVER destroy other peoples history. You must not rebase 
>      commits other people did. Basically, if it doesn't have your sign-off 
>      on it, it's off limits: you can't rebase it, because it's not yours.

It should be obvious that GitHub's [Squash and merge](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-pull-request-merges#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits) feature *destroys* other people's history by completely rewriting their PR branches.

I won't sit here and tell you that [Squash and merge](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-pull-request-merges#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits) is intrinsically *evil* ― I'm sure it has its uses.

However, if your team often finds itself having to deal with stale local branches (like you described), you might want to consider switching to a merge workflow that incorporates the history of your PRs *as-is* instead of destroying it.

Comment: Technically the squash-and-merge button uses the same algorithm as Git's `git merge --squash`: it doesn't build `S` atop the original branch, but rather directly atop the target, so no final rebase is required. The effect is the same, though.

Answer (score 0):

I came accross the same problem using PRs and squash merges and made a small command to cleanup the undesired branches, based on the ones that had an upstream branch.

It also avoids main branches deletion like `master`, `develop`, and `release` :

`git branch -d $(git branch --format "%(refname:short) %(upstream)" | awk '{if ($2) print $1;}' | grep -vE "release|develop|master") -f`

I made it using the answer to this question : [List all local branches without a remote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31776247/1667822)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `gh` command line tool](https://github.com/cli/cli) for this:

```
$ gh pr list -s merged --json headRefName -q '.[].headRefName' |
  sort -k 1,1 |
  join <(git branch | sort -k 1,1) -
```

`gh pr list ...` will display the branch names used when a commit was merged; we can compare it with the local list of branch names from `git branch` using [the `join` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join), though we need to `sort` both lists first.

More conservatively, you could check which ones match based on commit object id, rather than on the name:

```
$ gh pr list -s merged --json headRefOid -q '.[].headRefOid' |
  sort -k1,1 |
  join <(git branch --format '%(objectname) %(refname:short)' | sort -k1,1) -
```