# How to pass jq values from master shell script to child shell script

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, jq

In a shell script (let's say `master_script.sh`), I am trying to parse json file(`country.json`) using `jq` and passing those values to another shell script (`child_script.sh`) then print the values from `child_script` as I will be using it there.

***master_script.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash
$(jq -r ' .countries[] | .country as $cntry | .city[] | (.) as $ct |
"child_script.sh $cntry $ct"' country.json)
```

***country.json***

```
 {
        "countries": [
            {"country":"India","city":["India1","India2","India3"]},
            {"country":"USA","city":["USA1","USA2","USA3"]}
           
           ]
    }
```

***child_script.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash
country=$1
city=$2
echo "country: $country, city: $city"\n
# I need to use these two variables for further calculation
```

desired output from `child_script.sh` should be like: [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/cDiBeDmPRB)

```
country: India, city: India1
country: India, city: India2
country: India, city: India3
country: USA, city: USA1
country: USA, city: USA2
country: USA, city: USA3
```

But I am not able to achieve this.

Comment: Note that using command substitutions to generate shell commands generally doesn't work the way you'd expect -- see [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). (If it _did_ work the way you expected, that would make handling untrusted data in shell languages impossible, so it's a very good thing that it doesn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since some countries, such as "New Zealand", have spaces in their names, you will probably want to take that into account, e.g. as follows:

```
jq -r '.countries[]
       | .country as $country
       | .city[] | "\($country)\t\(.)"' | 
  while IFS=$'\t' read -r country city; do
     ./child_script.sh "$country" "$city"
  done
```

Comment: Even safer would be to use NUL delimiters rather than tabs. (When I'm feeling extra paranoid, I make jq remove any NULs in the data before printing them, and then add separating ones explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

`while read` is the generic approach, but we can take advantage of `xargs` since the loop body consists of executing a program.

```sh
jq -r '
   .countries[] |
   .country as $country |
   .city[] |
   @sh "\($country) \(.)"
' country.json |
xargs -rl ./child_script.sh
```

Comment: `xargs` unquoting isn't _quite_ compatible with POSIX sh parsing. I'd want to see a careful analysis that the subset emitted by `jq` is all handled by xargs before trusting this.

Comment: What about xargs versions that do not support `-r`? (See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803987/what-is-the-equivalent-to-xargs-r-under-osx)

Comment: @Charles Duffy, It just has to handle what jq produces, and it does.

Comment: @peak I don't think a universal solution is possible, at least not without making things really complicated. This will cover a lot of people. It will work on all GNU systems and then some. The rest will have to adjust as needed.

Answer (score -2):

I think you're looking for something like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
jq -r '.countries[] | .country + " " + .city[]' country.json | while read r; do
    ./child_script.sh "$r"
done
```

You need to loop on the results that you get from the `jq` command, and apply the script for each line.

Note: Remove the `\n` after the `echo` command in `child_script.sh`.

Comment: This won't work because it only passesg one string argument to the child script, which expects two arguments.